# How to position sibling element after position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am using a table to layout a certain html file that will be fed to email generators.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="that-row">
      <td style="font-size: 0;background: #fff; position: relative;" align="center">
        <img src="img_url" style="width:100%;margin: 0 0 20px;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;">
        <span style="width: 100%;line-height: 34px;font-family: Arial Regular, sans-serif;font-size: 22px;color: #474747;margin: 10px 0 0 0;">
         Lorem IpsumW
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="this-row">
      <td style="padding: 0 25px;font-size: 28px;line-height: 37px;color: #474747;text-align: center; position: relative;" align="center">
        <span style="display: block;text-align: center;color: #474747;font-size: 34px;font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial; margin: 0 0 21px;">LOREM IPSUM</span>
        <span style="text-align: left;margin: 0 auto;display: block;width: 83%;">lorem ipsum 123456</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the contents of the class "this-row" to be positioned below the "that-row" class. The current situation is the contents of "this-row" is positioned above "that-row" because "that-row" has no height.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: With the code that you have provided `this-row` is positioned below `that-row`, just as expected . Either you mean another thing or have a problem in another part of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend re-ordering table rows as it can change the default behavior of the table and there are better ways to handle what you are trying to accomplish.

Having said that, give flexbox a try. (not tested)

```
<table>
  <tbody style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <tr style="order:2;">
       <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="order:1;">
       <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```